# Unexpected htmlelement results from lxml

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

my code:

```py
from lxml import html
import request

currentPage = requests.get('https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/m000lyx0')
currentTree = html.fromstring(currentPage.content)
currentTree = html.parse("./index.html")
beilagen = currentTree.xpath('//div[@class="segment__track"]')
for x in beilagen:
    artist = x.xpath('//span[@class="artist"]/text()')
f.close()
```

I am trying to extract artist and song from the html. the variable `beilagen` is a list of all tracks. In the for loop I am trying to get each individual track but the variable *artist* holds all artists and my expectation would be that it only holds a single artist. Why do I get all artist as result? I am having a hard time to see the detailed contents of the `x` variable beyond `"<Element div at 0x10db2bad0>"`

many thanks

html: https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/m000lyx0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your `for` loop from

```
artist = x.xpath('//span[@class="artist"]/text()')
```

to

```
artist = x.xpath('.//span[@class="artist"]/text()')
```

and see if it works.

Comment: @patrup Glad it worked for you! If we're done, don't forget to accept the answer, please.